# How to use conditional statement to colour barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to colour `geom_bar` according to the number of the sample `ifelse(total > 90, "#FC2D00", "#008EFC")`. In other words, if the `total` > 90, the bar should be `red` but `total` < 90, it should be blue.

```
type = c("aa", "bb", "cc")
total = c(110, 90, 89)

df = data.frame(type, total)

df %>% 
ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = type, y = total)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity")
```

I tried

```
df %>% 
ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = type, y = total)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity",
           fill = (ifelse(
           levels(studies$total > 90, "#FC2D00", "#008EFC"))))
```

and also

```
df %>% 
mutate(fill = ifelse(levels(total > 90, "#FC2D00", "#008EFC"))) %>% 
ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = type, y = total)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity",
           fill = fill)
```

but it still not working. I'm not sure what is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need of `ifelse()` or `mutate()`. You can directly use the logical condition inside `fill` and then format using `scale_fill_manual()` for the colors and labels:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
type = c("aa", "bb", "cc")
total = c(110, 90, 89)
df = data.frame(type, total)
#Plot
df %>% 
  ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = type, y = total,fill=total > 90)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FC2D00","#008EFC"),
                    labels=c('TRUE'='>90','FALSE'='<90'))+
  labs(fill='Total')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that you can use `scale_fill_manual ` . That's awesome :) Thank you a lot Duck

Answer (score 2):

Move your fill inside of the `aes()`.

You should specify the colors in `scale_fill_manual()`:

```
df %>% 
mutate(fill = ifelse(levels(total > 90, "#FC2D00", "#008EFC"))) %>% 
ggplot2::ggplot(aes(x = type, y = total, fill = fill)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",
           stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values= c("red","blue"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ben. When I tried to copy your code, it gave me an error ```Problem with `mutate()` input `fill`` ```. Thank you anyway

Comment: but I wasn't aware of the use `scale_fill_manual()`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

In ggplot, we normally define color values in the scales, and legends are nicely autogenerated based on the data. So put in the data what you would want the legend labels to be, not the colors you want used.

```
df %>% 
mutate(emphasize = ifelse(total > 90, "> 90", "<= 90")) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = type, y = total, fill = emphasize)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("> 90" = "#FC2D00", "<= 90" = "#008EFC"))
```

We don't need to use `levels()` - it's a bad choice here because `total` is not a factor (and it doesn't return one value per row, it may have a different order than the data...). I also switched `geom_bar` to `geom_col` - `geom_col` has `stat = "identity"` as the default.

Comment: Thank you Gregor for the detailed explanation. It is working now but I don't want to generate a legend. I tried `geom_col(aes(fill = ifelse(totalSamples > 4000, "#FC2D00", "#008EFC")))` and it also working. Thanks a lot